# ArrayList not using the overridden equals

Tags: java, arraylist, overriding, equals

I'm having a problem with getting an ArrayList to correctly use an overriden equals.  the problem is that I'm trying to use the equals to only test for a single key field, and using ArrayList.contains() to test for the existence of an object with the correct field.  Here is an example

```
public class TestClass  {
    private static class InnerClass{    
    private final String testKey;
    //data and such

    InnerClass(String testKey, int dataStuff) {
        this.testKey =testKey;
        //etc
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object in) {
        System.out.println("reached here");
        if(in == null) {
        return false;
        }else if( in instanceof String) {
        String inString = (String) in;
        return testKey == null ? false : testKey.equals(inString);
        }else {
        return false;
        }       
    }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
    ArrayList<InnerClass> objectList = new ArrayList<InnerClass>();
    //add some entries
    objectList.add(new InnerClass("UNIQUE ID1", 42));
    System.out.println( objectList.contains("UNIQUE ID1")); 
    }    
}
```

What worries me is that not only am I getting false on the output, but I'm also not getting the "reached here" output.

Does anyone have any ideas why this override is being completely ignored?  Is there some subtlety with overrides and inner classes I don't know of?

Edit:
Having problems with the site so I cant seem to mark the answered. 
Thanks for the quick response: yes an oversight on my part that it is the String .equals thta is called, not my custom one.  I guess it's old fashioned checks for now

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you check sources of `ArrayList`, you will see that it calls `equals` of other object. In your case it will call `equals` of `String "UNIQUE ID1"` which will check that other object is not of type `String` and just returns `false`:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return indexOf(o) >= 0;
}

public int indexOf(Object o) {
    ...     
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
        return i;
    ...
    return -1;
}
```

For your case call `contains` with `InnerClass` that only contains `id`:

```
objectList.contains(new InnerClass("UNIQUE ID1"))
```

Don't forget to implement `equals` for `InnerClass` which compares `id` only.

Comment: Thanks. That suggestion about new InnerClass() was really helpful as well. :)

Comment: In my opinion the implementation of indexOf should be the other way around: elementData[i].equals(o)...

Answer (score 7):

According to [the JavaDoc of `List.contains(o)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29), it is defined to return `true`

> if and only if this list contains at least one element `e` such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))`.

Note that this definition calls `equals` on `o`, which is the **parameter** and **not** the element that is in the `List`.

Therefore `String.equals()` will be called and not `InnerClass.equals()`.

Also note that [the contract for `Object.equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) states that

> It is *symmetric*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return `true` if and only if `y.equals(x)` returns `true`.

But you violate this constraint, since `new TestClass("foo", 1).equals("foo")` returns `true` but `"foo".equals(new TestClass("foo", 1))` will always return `false`.

Unfortunately this means that your use case (a custom class that can be equal to another standard class) can not be implemented in a completely conforming way.

*If* you still want to do something like this, you'll have to read the specification (and sometimes the implementation) of all your collection classes **very** carefully and check for pitfalls such as this.

Comment: Been working too long hours.  Never a good sign when you start forgetting the basics, or misreading api specifications.  I've found the workaround of having a constructor of new InnerClass(String testKey) to make a test object, but with the actually data as null/0s.

Answer (score 3):

You're invoking `contains` with an argument that's a `String` and not an `InnerClass`:

```
System.out.println( objectList.contains("UNIQUE ID1"))
```

In my JDK:

```
public class ArrayList {

    public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return indexOf(o) >= 0;
    }

    public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        // omitted for brevity - aix
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (o.equals(elementData[i])) // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
    }
}
```

Note how `indexOf` calls `o.equals()`. In your case, `o` is a `String`, so your `objectList.contains` will be using `String.equals` and not `InnerClass.equals`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you need to also override `hashCode()` but this is not the main problem here. You are having an asymmetric `equals(..)` method. The docs make it clear that it should be symmetric:

> It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y, x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.

And what you observe is an unexpected behaviour due to broken contract.

Create an utility method that iterates all items and verifies with `equals(..)` on the string:

```
public static boolean containsString(List<InnerClass> items, String str) {
    for (InnerClass item : items) {
        if (item.getTestKey().equals(str)) {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can do a similar thing with guava's `Iterables.any(..)` method:

```
final String str = "Foo";
boolean contains = Iterables.any(items, new Predicate<InnerClass>() {
   @Override
   public boolean apply(InnerClass input){ 
       return input.getTestKey().equals(str);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your equals implementation is wrong. Your in parameter should not be a `String`. It should be an `InnerClass`.

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (this == o) return true;
  if (!(o instanceof InnerClass) return false;
  InnerClass that = (InnerClass)o;
  // check for null keys if you need to
  return this.testKey.equals(that.testKey);
}
```

(Note that `instanceof null` returns false, so you don't need to check for null first).

You would then test for existence of an *equivalent* object in your list using:

```
objectList.contains(new InnerClass("UNIQUE ID1"));
```

But if you really want to check for InnerClass by String key, why not use `Map<String,InnerClass>` instead?

Comment: To be blunt it's been some 6 years since I last used Java and while I've got a coder's mindset, I lack experience.  I'm not yet fully familiar with Maps, or Java hashing just yet since I learnt C originally.  Using java now because for small application / tool development it's a lot faster and I need decent international and platform independence.  I have added a constructor (and for some of my other classes which implement an abstract parent, a sister class) to make a testobject with just the test key.

Answer (score 0):

Although not answering your question, many Collections use `hashcode()`. You should override that too to "agree" with `equals()`.

Actually, you should *always* implement both `equals` and `hashcode` together, and they should always be consistent with each other. As the javadoc for `Object.equals()` states:

> Note that it is generally necessary to
>   override the hashCode method whenever
>   this method is overridden, so as to
>   maintain the general contract for the
>   hashCode method, which states that
>   equal objects must have equal hash
>   codes.

Specifically, many Collections rely on this contract being upheld - behaviour is undefined otherwise.

Comment: While it's true that you should implement both, it does not help in this specific case, since `ArrayList` is not in any way hash-based: it doesn't care about the `hashCode()` implementation.

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't use `hashCode`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.  **My suggestion would be to avoid overriding the equals entirely if you are not familiar with it** and extend it into a new implementation like so...

```
class MyCustomArrayList extends ArrayList<InnerClass>{

    public boolean containsString(String value){
        for(InnerClass item : this){
            if (item.getString().equals(value){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Then you can do something like

```
List myList = new MyCustomArrayList()
myList.containsString("some string");
```

I suggest this because if you override the equals should also override the hashCode and it seems you are lacking a little knowledge in this area - so i would just avoid it.

Also, the contains method calls the equals method which is why you are seeing the "reached here".  Again if you don't understand the call flow i would just avoid it.

Comment: I do understand the call flow, but missed that it was using String.equals rather than InnerClass.equals.  As ArrayList is not hash based I saw no need to include the hashCode in the snippet.  Naturally I include a hashCode override, even if all it needs here is to return testKey.hashCode()

Answer (score 0):

in the other way, your equal method gets called if you change your code as follows. hope this clears the concept.

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;    
import java.util.List;

public class TestClass  {
    private static class InnerClass{    
        private final String testKey;
        //data and such

        InnerClass(String testKey, int dataStuff) {
            this.testKey =testKey;
            //etc
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals (Object in1) {
            System.out.println("reached here");
            if(in1 == null) {
                return false;
            }else if( in1 instanceof InnerClass) {
                return ((InnerClass) this).testKey == null ? false : ((InnerClass) this).testKey.equals(((InnerClass) in1).testKey);
            }else {
                return false;
            }       
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        ArrayList<InnerClass> objectList = new ArrayList<InnerClass>();
        InnerClass in1 = new InnerClass("UNIQUE ID1", 42);
        InnerClass in2 = new InnerClass("UNIQUE ID1", 42);

        //add some entries
        objectList.add(in1);
        System.out.println( objectList.contains(in2)); 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As many posts have said, the problem is that list.indexOf(obj) function calls "equals" of the obj, not the items on the list.

I had the same problem and "contains()" didn't satisfy me, as I need to know where is the element!. My aproach is to create an empty element with just the parameter to compare, and then call indexOf.

Implement a function like this,

```
public static InnerClass empty(String testKey) {
    InnerClass in = new InnerClass();
    in.testKey =testKey;
    return in;
}
```

And then, call indexOf like this:

```
ind position = list.indexOf(InnerClass.empty(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code.

First:
The "contains" method called on "objectList" object should pass a new InnerClass object as the parameter.

Second:
The equals method (should accept the parameter as Object, and is correct) should handle the code properly according to the received object.
 Like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean equals (Object in) {
        System.out.println("reached here");
        if(in == null) {
        return false;
        }else if( in instanceof InnerClass) {
        String inString = ((InnerClass)in).testKey;
        return testKey == null ? false : testKey.equals(inString);
        }else {
        return false;
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This post was first written before Java 8 was available but now that it's 2017 instead of using the List.containts(...) method you can use the new Java 8 way like this:

```
System.out.println(objectList.stream().filter(obj -> obj.getTestKey().equals("UNIQUE ID1")).findAny().isPresent());
```

And give your TestClass a getter for your testKey field:

```
public String getTestKey() {

   return testKey;
}
```

The benefit of this approach is that you don't have to modify the equals or hash method and you'll look like a boss to your peers!