# How to typecast e.getSource() to return the index of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, mouseevent

I am trying to determine when an object (that was part of an arrayList) has been clicked upon and then I call some code using the index that I got returned.

Here is my code snippet

```
this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            if (cursorState==1) {
                 int indx = trees.indexOf(e.getSource()); 
                 Tree tempTree = trees.get(indx); 
                 tempTree.killTree(); //Code I call for the object that was clicked on
                 System.out.println("indx"); //Troubleshoot
                 repaint();
            }


        }
```

I keep getting an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException: -1.

From my searching it seems that it isn't getting the index at all.

Comment: What class is `trees`?  And what generic type argument did you instantiate it with?

Comment: `indexOf` is obviously returning `-1`. Wich means the returned value from `e.getSource()` does not exist  in the Tree.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have equals method overridden in the class type of trees object to get the index of any object in array through indexOf method.

Refer [ArrayList not using the overridden equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596778/arraylist-not-using-the-overridden-equals) for overriding equals method.

Comment: Not sure what I would override it with. With a little bit of research, I tried this, but it doesn't work public                                                                    int hashCode() {
     return java.util.Objects.hashCode(id);
 }
 
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Tree) {
      //id comparison
      Tree mo = (Tree)o;
      return mo.id.equals(id);
    }
    return false;
  }

Comment: Can you clarify the types of trees and e.getSource() objects.

Comment: trees (the array list) is of type Tree, which is why in my main code i typed it with Tree. Tree also does not extend anything. I am sorry that this seems to be going over my head. In simpler terms, what would equals code look like for a simple class that has one method drawTree(Graphics2D g2).

Comment: Thank you so much for trying but it still doesn't work. Same error. It's probably because I don't get it. What kind of field is id?